# Inductive proof for recursive formula $a_n=4-a_{n-1}$

Tags: recursion

I have a recursive formula $a_n=4-a_{n-1}, a_3=7$ and I had to solve this and check the correction of the answer with induction.

I started solving this and the solved formula is: $a_n=-2((-1)^{n-3}-1)+7(-1)^{n-3}$.

1. Base case $n=3$ is true
2. Let's assume this is true for $n=k$
3. Thus this should be true for $n=k+1$

   $a_{n=k+1}=5(-1)^{k-2}+2$.

I don't know how to continue from this place, please someone help me and explain this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $-2((-1)^{n-3} - 1) + 7(-1)^{n-3} = 5(-1)^{n-3} + 2$.

Assuming $a_n = 5(-1)^{n-3} + 2$, the recursive formula tells us that

$$a_{n+1} = 4 - a_n = 4 - [5(-1)^{n-3} + 2] = -5(-1)^{n-3} + 2 = 5(-1)^{n-2}+2.$$

This proves the result.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Prove that $a_{n+2}=a_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but can you explain further, please? Because I am very confused right now about this

Comment: My suggestion would be to *not* use induction, but instead to prove the hint. Then you get all values of $a_n$ from the values of $a_3$ and $a_4$, which you can quickly compute.